# How to remove boot loader entry on Windows-8?

Tags: bootloader, windows-8

I have just installed Windows-8 preview twice, because at first I accidentally installed it at the wrong partition and now I have got 2 entries with Windows-8 in the boot loader and would like to get rid of the other one.

So how can I remove an extra boot loader entry in Windows-8?

Comment: Did you format the first partition where you installed it accidently? If you did not then you have to format it again as the second boot entry has been merged with this one and will cause not to boot up the system if you delete it. Or may be the `fix mbr` could help you but I am not sure.

Comment: i formatted the first partition on the install screen before i installed it again on the second one, fixmbr doesn't seem to be available in win 8 :>

Comment: Try EasyBcd edit which can help you.

Comment: voted your answer up :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also use MSConfig, if you don't want to download a third party tool to do something already built into Windows.

Comment: upvoted your answer, i didn't know that msconfig still existed, i used it several times on earlier versions..

Comment: Still works in Windows 10 (or rather Windows-Technical Preview) too

Comment: Boot loader shows 2 options, but only the current OS is shown in msconfig

Comment: Actually boot loader shows 3 options; used instructions at http://www.oxhow.com/how-to-remove-earlier-version-of-windows-from-windows-boot-menu/ to remove one of them; now I see "Windows 10" which I want to keep, and one which I don't want to keep "Microsoft Windows XP Professional Setup"

Comment: EasyBCD also only shows one option. It even says that Windows 10 is the default, which it is not. If I don't press anything in windows boot manager, windows xp setup starts.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) which has the ability to control the bootloader and with it you can delete the bootloader entry.

Comment: That is fast becoming a very useful tool. Remember that only the beta supports win 8 (last I checked at any rate)

Comment: realy nice tool with plenty of features to tune the boot loader

Answer (score 1):

Go to `msconfig` (Windows key + R). In the Boot tab, all operating systems will be shown. Remove the other operating system, and set Windows 7 as your default OS. See the image below for a screenshot of the Boot tab (note that I have only one OS on this machine).

[image]