# Remove dual boot screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove boot loader entry on Windows-8?](https://superuser.com/questions/476847/how-to-remove-boot-loader-entry-on-windows-8)

some time ago i bought an SSD and since i had to reinstall windows i bought windows 8 with it.
I kept windows 7 on my old HDD and i installed Windows 8 on the SSD.
For some time i had both, and a dual boot screen would allow me to switch between them.

But now i deleted the windows 7 partition and merged it to the partition where i keep all my files, movies etc.

But i still have the dual boot screen showing up with windows 8 and windows 7 options.
**How can i remove the dual boot screen and just make it boot to windows 8?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fixmbr was the command to use.  Need to bootup to command prompt, I used to use bartpe cds for this, but now it looks like you should bootup off the Win8 cd.  Check out this page on the steps to follow: [Repair / Fix MBR in Windows 8 using the Command Prompt](http://windows8themes.org/repair-fix-mbr-in-windows-8-using-the-command-prompt.html)

Might be another way as well.  Used to be you could edit the boot.ini, you should be able to select the default OS to boot to and how long to wait for input, 0 seconds if you don't want to wait.  Try these steps: Right click My Computer --> Properties --> Advanced System Settings --> Under Startup and Recovery select settings --> Under Default Operating System, use the pulldown arror and select which OS to select as the default on Boot-->Click OK-->click Apply-->click OK-- Reboot.   Information from [edit-boot-windows](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/2924-63-edit-boot-windows)

Comment: I just found out i have another problem, the HDD is setup as boot partition and the SSD isn't, so i have to make the SSD as boot now

Answer (score 0):

Use [EasyBCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD). It's a free program home and non-profit use, which will provide a very simple fix for this issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid (and downvoted) if the linked page changes. See [How To Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) for why it is important.