# How to uninstall windows 7 in dual boot with windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, multi-boot

My pc has  3 partition C, D and E.
first i installed win 8 on C and then win 7 in D in dual boot.
now how to uninstall win 7 and only win 8 installed.

Comment: Delete the partition and fix the boot menu.

Comment: how to fix boot menu

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/476847/how-to-remove-boot-loader-entry-on-windows-8, http://superuser.com/questions/517002/remove-dual-boot-screen, http://superuser.com/questions/412777/restoring-the-windows-7-boot-loader-after-uninstalling-windows-8?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply open the Drive Manager and delete the Windows 7 partition. You do not need to modify boot menu, it will take care of itself. It did for me, anyway. I just did this a few days ago.

Comment: thanks
i delete partition and creat new volume.
it became logical drive .
Before it was primary partition.
Is it Ok?

Comment: Yes! A logical drive is used like any partition except it can't load an OS.